# Disable single view in register_post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I'm looking for a solution to properly disable the single view for a custom post type. Is it possible in register_post_type ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you are using `register_post_type` use this.

```
'publicly_queryable'  => false
```

Note: This hides your post to display in archive pages also.

Comment: It will disable the archive page... I'm looking for a manner to disable only the single view...

Comment: what do you mean by disable single views.?

Comment: There is an argument called "has_archive". I'm looking for "has_single"